# Repair Corrupt Bitlocker Files - Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8, encryption, windows-8.1, bitlocker

In the past I have never used BitLocker, but recently I have become interested in setting it up on both my mom's computer as well as my own. We both had Windows 8 Pro on which we never used Bitlocker, and have both upgraded to Windows 8.1 Pro. Since becoming interested in BitLocker, I have configured it on my mom's computer, and now want to do it on mine, but I have a problem: my BitLocker isn't working. I spoke with Microsoft support about it, and they determined that my BitLocker is corrupt for some reason. Since I couldn't pay them to fix it for me, I am left to deal with it on my own. How can I repair my corrupt BitLocker without losing all of my data? I looked in my `%RootPath%\System32` folder where the BitLocker files are stored, and they are all there. The only problem is that when I try to run them, nothing happens. On top of that, the link in the Control Panel for BitLocker is missing, and I think that's mostly where the problem lies. How can I resolve this?

Post mirrored on [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-system/repair-corrupt-bitlocker-files-windows-81/bdf7fb69-e108-49f9-9aac-db5f1aa683b7?tm=1392084033120).

Comment: Looks like you’re having [the same problem](https://superuser.com/questions/729379/bitlocker-missing-in-windows-8-1-pro) as I do.  I was able to use the BitLocker UI at first, then it went missing at some point.

Comment: @JCChu I never did find a solution to the problem. I just ran a Windows 8.1 repair. I had to reinstall all of my programs, but my personal files were kept.

Comment: I resolved the issue by enabling Shell Hardware Detection...  @DavidB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My computer apparently became infected with malware at some point that messed up BitLocker. I was able to resolve the issue by reinstalling Windows 8.1.