# BitLocker missing in Windows 8.1 Pro

Tags: windows-8, shell, windows-8.1, encryption, bitlocker

This is a TPM-free laptop dual booting to Windows 8.1 Pro and Windows 7 Pro.  BitLocker was turned on in Windows 8 Pro (before upgrading to 8.1) via group policy.

Everything was fine initially, but some time later (I don’t remember exactly when, but it should be *before* upgrading to Windows 8.1), I noticed that, in Windows 8 or 8.1,

- the BitLocker overlay icons were gone;
- BitLocker commands were missing in context menus;
- the BitLocker icon no longer appears in Control Panel; and
- while “Manage BitLocker” still appears in “Search” (Windows–Q) results, nothing appears when I open it (same with `Control  /name Microsoft.BitLockerDriveEncryption`).

Meanwhile everything is fine in Windows 7 Pro.

I’ve checked shell integration (places like `HKCR\Drive\shell\manage-bde`, etc.) and found no problem; I can still use `manage-bde` and `bdeunlock`; and I still get the toast message after an encrypted volume is mounted (at least before the SD card reader gave up).

I’ve also looked at event logs and found no anomalies.

If anyone has any idea what is going on please, please tell me.

Comment: You used the Windows Store to perform this upgrade?  You have all released patches for Windows 8.1 installed?

Comment: Yes; yes.  @Ramhound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved after the Shell Hardware Detection service was enabled.